# Create JSON object from c# class

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

I have a view model which looks like so:

```
public class CategoriesJsonViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Description> UsedDescriptions { get; set; }
    public List<Description> UnusedDescriptions { get; set; }
}
```

I am creating a List of CategoriesJsonViewModel in my controller and trying to send it to the client browser in Json format. I use Json() method to do that:

```
List<CategoriesJsonViewModel> categoriesVM = new List<CategoriesJsonViewModel>();
List<Category> categories = repo.GetAllCategories();
foreach(var i in categories)
{
            CategoriesJsonViewModel categoryVM = new CategoriesJsonViewModel();
            categoryVM.Id = i.Id;
            categoryVM.Title = i.Title;
            categoriesVM.Add(categoryVM);
            categoryVM.UsedDescriptions = repo.GetUsedDescriptions(i.Id);
            categoryVM.UnusedDescriptions = repo.GetUnusedDescriptions(i.Id);
 }


 return Json(categoriesVM);
```

Although the categoriesVM object is being built properly, I do not get appropriate Json object from it for some reason. Why is it so?

Comment: "I do not get appropriate Json object from it" - what **specifically** is different / inappropriate?

Comment: You might have to show the expected vs. actual JSON output.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you get the outputted json and put into [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com)

That'll help you find out what is causing the json to be invalid. It may be something to do with your definition of the Description object as your CategoriesJsonViewModel looks like it should be ok.

Comment: How can I grab the JSON being produced in Json()?

Comment: In your controller make sure you have return Json(categoriesVM, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) - you should then be able to see the json sent back in Firebug.